# how to change title of popupMenu item in android?

Tags: android, popupmenu

### popupMenu has two items and the implementation is in onBindView of recycler view where I want to change title of item on click.

**if is not possible then please give me some other solution to show menu on recyclerview card**

feedmenu is icon where the popup menu is shown on click

```
finalHolder.feed_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, v);
                final MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.feed_menu, popup.getMenu());
               final Menu popupMenu = popup.getMenu();
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.bookmark:
                        popupMenu.findItem(R.id.bookmark).setVisible(false);
                                Toast.makeText(context, "item1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case R.id.report:
                                 Toast.makeText(context, "item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popup.show();
            }
        });
```

### **/menu/feed_menu.xml**

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:title="menu" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bookmark"
        android:title="@string/feed_bookmark" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/report"
        android:title="@string/feed_report" />
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's assume that you have an `Adapter` and a `ViewHolder`, make an instance of a `PopupMenu` on your ViewHolder, for a cleaner look, implement `OnClickListener`, switch on the view ids to trigger the button/view you want, on that, simply initialize the PopupMenu and do what you want.
for changing the titles, if the actions are also different, I suggest you to have multiple menu items and handle them by removing the items you don't need, for example:

```html
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

  /**
   * Views
   */
   private ImageButton options;
   private PopupMenu mPopupMenu;
   
   public MemberViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        options = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_my_viewholder_options);
        mPopupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, options);
        options.setOnClickListener(this);
   }
    
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
        final int position = getAdapterPosition();
        if (view.getId() == R.id.item_my_viewholder_options){
            mPopupMenu.getMenu().clear();
            MenuInflater inflater = mPopupMenu.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, mPopupMenu.getMenu());
            if (model.isX) {
                mPopupMenu.getMenu().removeItem(R.id.menu_item_y);
            } else if (model.isY) {
                mPopupMenu.getMenu().removeItem(R.id.menu_item_x);
            }

            mPopupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
              // your logic
            });
            mPopupMenu.show();
        }
   }

}
```

Comment: but how to change item title on item click i already tried `Menu popupMenu = popup.getMenu(); ` and then on itemclick  popupMenu.findItem(R.id.bookmark).setVisible(false); but this was not work

Comment: check out my edited answer, by removing/adding items inside your menu.

Comment: @PrabhatRai visibility won't help you, first make sure every time you're clearing the menu, then inflate your menu and remove the items you don't need.

Comment: @PrabhatRai like this:
if (model.isX) {
                mPopupMenu.getMenu().removeItem(R.id.menu_item_y);
            } else if (model.isY) {
                mPopupMenu.getMenu().removeItem(R.id.menu_item_x);
            }

Comment: @PrabhatRai are you sure your calling .show() and also you're not removing all the items?